# Zoom in/out gesture UIView

Tags: events, uiview, zooming, multi-touch

i've been trying to capture gesture zoom in/out in a UIView.

Code:

```
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
NSArray *twoTouches = [allTouches allObjects];
UITouch *first = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:0]; 
UITouch *second = [twoTouches objectAtIndex:1]; 
CGPoint firstPoint = [first locationInView:self];
CGPoint secondPoint = [second locationInView:self];
CGFloat initialDistance = [distanceBetweenPoints(firstPoint, secondPoint)];
```

I'm using the function distanceBetweenPoints, the problem is that firstPoint or secondPoint always is 0.00, 0.00 and for that reason the result is the value of one of them.

I need that the booth values should be distint to zero for obtain the real distance.

The frame of the view is: (0, 0, 320, 417).

The functionality that i'm developing is something like zoom in/out of google maps.

Thanks,

Comment: What platform are we talking about? iphone?

Comment: Yes, iphone.

I found the answer.

The problem was that the uiview need it the attribute self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

For that reason the multitouch worked but not so well.

Thanks,

Comment: Please, when you find the answer yourself, add it as an answer, not as a comment. Otherwise your question appears unanswered in searches.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the uiview need it the attribute self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; For that reason the multitouch worked but not so well.